# How to fix ConvertException while writting to a txt file with the FileHelpers library?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I need to read a csv file that occasionally has int values in DateTime fields due to input error. But i still need to save those values so i could later write them into an output file.

Data example:

```
  "517506","m","2012-11-07","LTU","4","m","0"
  "517507","m","9","BLR","2","d","0"
```

At first i thought the problem is with the reading itself, but then i noticed that i get this error

```
  Unhandled Exception: FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting '9' to type: 'DateTime'.  There are less chars in the Input String than in the Format string: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

when i try to convert those int values back to DateTime value when writing the output to a .txt file.

I would appreciate any help.

My code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Citizen>();

        var result = engine2.ReadFile(@"C:\registered_people.csv");
        engine.WriteFile(@"C:\FileOut2.txt", result);
    }
```

Citizen class:

```
  public class Citizen
{

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public int? id;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    [FieldNullValue("")]
    public string gender;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "")]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime birthDate;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    [FieldNullValue("")]
    public string nationality;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public int? countyNo;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    [FieldNullValue("")]
    public string familyStat;

    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public int? children;

}
```

Comment: Read them as text and convert them to datetime if they have the correct format.

Comment: Since when is "9" a valid date value? That's what the data has in the 2nd record for "BirthDate". Looks like someone coded an age there, when you really need the full birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Read them as `string` properties and convert them after you have imported the records. You should have two classes: `CitizenSpec` which is your FileHelpers class and describes the import file (with public `string` fields to prevent conversion errors); and `Citizen` which is your *real* class with properties, backing fields, methods, business logic, etc. Then after `engine.ReadFile` use a loop or Linq to convert the `CitizenSpec` records into `Citizen` records.
2. Alternatively provide your own tolerant `FieldConverter` which defines what invalid inputs to ignore. See [the documentation on custom converters](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/).